# Multiple Delimiter Date Regular Expression

Tags: regex, validation

I am working on creating a regular expression to verify a date in multiple formats and I have found plenty of info on how to handle a date in the following formats:

```
06/19/2013
06-19-2013
06 19 2013
06.19.2013
```

but I cannot seem to get the regex to handle

```
06192013
```

Here is my regular expression:

```
((0?[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.]((19|20)?[0-9]{2}
```

How do I handle the date with no delimiters?

Comment: You just need to add `?` to `[- \/.]` so it becomes `[- \/.]?`. Which comes to the following conclusion: you should learn the basics of regex !

Comment: Your regex misses a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Btw, the format order might be - if non-American, espcially when dotted - `DD MM YYYY` (for example: `20. 6. 2013`). You also might want to allow the international standard format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Also, as an additional comment, even though I appreciate the effort you've put in the validation on the date (days between 1 and 31, months between 1 and 12 with the optional leading 0), I'd like to point out that performing date validation using regex is going to be really painful. What do you think of 31th February ?

Comment: @Josay Our SO fellow [kaᵠ](http://stackoverflow.com/users/731947) has written something awesome, take a [look](http://regex101.com/r/dE8hM7) :D

Comment: @HamZa Thanks for this. I didn't know that tool and I had it to my personal collection.

Comment: @Josay Hmmm I was more referring to the regex that validates dates even for the month february (also for leap years). Aside from that, note that the website uses PCRE PHP as regex flavor.

Comment: @HamZa Yep, I knew that. However, I didn't realise that it was going as far as leap years. This is plain crazy... and I like it :-)

Comment: Also, as "Gregory dropped 10 days to bring the calendar back into synchronization with the seasons. Accordingly, when the new calendar was put in use, the error accumulated in the 13 centuries since the Council of Nicaea was corrected by a deletion of ten days. The last day of the Julian calendar was Thursday, 4 October 1582 and this was followed by the first day of the Gregorian calendar, Friday, 15 October 1582 (the cycle of weekdays was not affected)." You can still get invalid dates corresponding to one of these dropped days ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make it [optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html):

```
(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.]?(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.]?(19|20)?[0-9]{2}
                       ^                                ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `DateTime.TryParseExact()`?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx

Comment: The OP didn't mention the language he's using, thus this might be irrelevant.

Comment: If they use .NET, this would be a lot easier.